# How to change user for a bunch of systemd service files?

Tags: text-processing, systemd

I have a bunch of service files in `/etc/systemd/service/myapp.*.service`

Each one has a line that looks like...

```
User=Foo
```

...and I need to change all these .service files so they all say...

```
User=Bar
```

How do I do this efficiently?

Comment: To be clear.  I did not add the 'text-processing' tag to this question.  It's a systemd configuration question, and one answer was "use text processing to configure it".  I don't think the text-processing tag belongs here.

Comment: The text-processing tag definitely belongs, honestly the systemd tag probably does not.  This is a question about modifying text files and has very little, if nothing, to do with systemd

Comment: Actually, it has quite a lot to do with systemd, because the real task is not _I want to change these text files arbitrarily._ but is _I want to reconfigure my systemd services to work differently._

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Who says that you need to change the files at all?  ☺

```
find /etc/systemd/service/ -maxdepth 1 -name 'myapp.*.service' |
while read -r i
do
    printf '[Service]\nUser=%s\n' 'Bar' > ${i}.d/change-user.conf
done
```

Getting the vanilla service definition back again is somewhat easier this way.

```
rm -- /etc/systemd/service/myapp.*.service.d/change-user.conf
```

Making these all *one single file* that applies across a whole bunch of services is of course just a simple exercise in the use of hard links.

```
install -d /etc/systemd/temp
printf '[Service]\nUser=%s\n' 'Bar' > /etc/systemd/temp/change-user.conf
find /etc/systemd/service/ -maxdepth 1 -name 'myapp.*.service' |
while read -r i
do
    ln /etc/systemd/temp/change-user.conf ${i}.d/change-user.conf
done
```

This is of course the official way to do this sort of thing with package-supplied and runtime-generated units, moreover.  You are supposed *not* to change such unit files.

## Further reading

- Lennart Poettering (2013-10-07).  [`systemd.unit`](http://freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html). systemd manual pages.  freedesktop.org.

Comment: This is interesting.  Can you explain it a bit more please so that I'm sure I understand what your intent is?  Especially the part about the .conf?  Does it supersede settings in the original .service file?  Also, now you've basically written an entire script to generate the relevant snippet.  If I were to do this a subsequent time, would I not then have the same problem as before (how to change all the snippets?) I would overwrite them all right?  If there were a way to point all the myapp.*.service configs to the same snippet, that would be interesting.

Answer (score 5):

using `sed`:

```
sed -i 's/^User=Foo$/User=Bar/' /etc/systemd/service/myapp.*.service
```

Comment: I appreciate the simplicity of this answer.  This is a very useful general technique.

Comment: I recommend using anchors, like `s/^User=Foo$/User=Bar/`, so that the search doesn't match things like `# User=Foo # original value` or `User=Foodle`.